# PHP pass mysql query as variable to second php script when requested

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I've been teaching myself php & mysql & have found this site invaluable. Thanks to all who answer questions.

I have found several q&a's that are close to this & they HAVE helped to point me in the right direction but I can't quite get this to work.

Here's what I'm trying to do:  Pass a constructed SQL query to a second php script so that the results can be displayed in a new window.  I can't quite seem to get the syntax right to pass the sql
query ($sql) to open.window correctly.  A matter of quotes I 
think.  I have tried echo instead of print, single quotes with double quotes inside, using ('$sql'), but nothing seems to work.

I do need this to be called by a variable, so that it is after the submit is given.  I would prefer not to have a second submit

Help?

```
if (isset($_POST['NEWWINDOW'])) {

  echo "<script>window.open("results.php?sql=$sql)</script>";

}
```

Comment: Do **NOT** do this. This is extraordinarily dangerous and plain stupid. You're TRUSTING the user to not simply hit your script with `results.php?sql=DROP+DATABASE+DATABASE()`. Boom goes your DB.

Comment: This script could have VERY bad consequences for you

Answer (score 0):

This will concatinate your $sql-variable with the rest of the string, however doing this you should keep in mind to sanitize your sql in result.php before submiting it to your database.

```
if (isset($_POST['NEWWINDOW'])) {
  echo "<script>window.open('results.php?sql=".$sql."')</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
      if (isset($_POST['NEWWINDOW'])) {

      echo "<script>window.open('results.php?sql=$sql')</script>";

      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Was able to get this going with $_SESSION variables.  Avoided passing the sql query in the URL as advised.

Comment: Yes we can do. If it id value please do some encrption or check for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Thank you each for your responses.  This query form is private, & I will be the only one using it... (behind firewall), so the risk is minimal.  However, the point is well made & I would certainly rather learn to do it the right way than the wrong way.  The database is important.  Recommendations?

Neither of the two offered suggestions as to syntax work for me.

I made sure & copy the syntax exactly.  In both (all three cases) the window.open fails to open a window.  I finally cut & pasted to be sure, but the behavior is the same.. the window does not even open.